# How to solve the publish of obtaining the actual application path base .net Staandard libaray 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

How to solve the publish of obtaining the actual application path. When merging into one file, the path to get the current exe program is the running path of the temporary folder, not the actual application path.

Comment: Does same happen on build machine?  Is application using a File Dialog?  Often File Dialogs will default to last time used folder which may of been another application.  So adding the default folder may help.  Are you using any dll which may be setting the default folder.  Are you specifying any folders in a config file?  The config may need to change.

Comment: I have‘nt set the default app path,as the standard libray 2 will be refered  by diferent application,such as  web asp.net MVC, other standard library,net core winform... ’

Comment: C#  string  appPath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;   this coe still can not solve the problem

Comment: Add a Console.WriteLine(appPath) to application and see what you get on build machine and deploy machine.

Comment: Soucce CODE : [link]https://github.com/lawtatfaitony/PathManage

Comment: Please edit to include your current code.